# Is $x^TAy\geq 0$ when A is positive semidefinite and $x,y \neq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis

I know that when A is positive semidefinite then for any $x \in R^n,x\neq 0$ then $x^TAx\geq 0$

What about I have two different vectors $x,y$?
Is $x^TAy\geq 0$ when A is positive semidefinite and $x,y \neq 0$

$A$: $nxn$ positive semi-definite matrix.

$x \in R^n ,x \neq 0$

$y \in R^n ,x \neq 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Consider $A$ is the identity, $y=-x$, where x is not the zero vector.  Then $x^T Ay=-x^T x <0$

Comment: Is it true if $x^Ty \geq 0$?